# Bukkit ItemStack serialization using Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson, bukkit

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize an ItemStack using the Jackson JSON library. So far I have managed to serialize the ItemStack however when I go to deserialize it, I get the following error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment]`

I'm not sure why this is. I have tried different versions of the Jackson library to no avail, I still get the exact same error. I have tried serializing ItemStacks with and without enchantments and I still get it. Any help would be appreciated here.

I am using the below code to deserialize my ItemStack:

```
try {
    ItemStack item = objectMapper.readValue(gang.getVaultItems().get(slot), ItemStack.class);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to likely have to use custom deserialization for this. You can read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). It is worth noting that by default Bukkit uses a fairly custom YAML implementation to handle serialization and deserialization. Look into [ConfigurationSerializable](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/serialization/ConfigurationSerializable.html) if you're not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the Enchantment key. You can do this using KeyDeserializer.

As far as I understand, this is because Enchantment is an abstract class, and Jackson needs Enchantment to be of type String, not of type Enchantment.

```
public class EnchantmentDeserialize extends KeyDeserializer {

@Override
public Object deserializeKey(String s, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    return Enchantment.getByKey(NamespacedKey.fromString(s));
    }
}

SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("CustomItemSerialize", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
```

And add Desererializer to Object Mapped like that:

```
simpleModule.addKeyDeserializer(Enchantment.class, new EnchantmentDeserialize());

objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```